# Word wrapping in ng-grid header cells

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-grid, word-wrap

I have a question regarding word-wrapping in ng-grid's header cells. I have tried adding

```
word-wrap: break-word !important;
```

to a custom header cell template (as a style attribute on the ngCellText div), in the css for both the cellClass and headerClass I have defined for the column, and have tried making the headerRowHeight much higher to accommodate the word wrapping. However, it doesn't seem like this is working, as the header cell text still has ellipses (...) after it when the column is not wide enough to fit the entire text. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try setting a max-width on that same col.

Comment: hey @Billy unfortunately that doesn't do it, the ellipses are still there and the words aren't being broken.

Comment: Did you add your style to .ngHeaderText ? You can try setting text-overflow to 'clip' instead of 'ellipses'.

Comment: @Billy I just added the word-wrap: break word to .ngHeaderText, and still nothing. How would I set the text-overflow? Is that a valid CSS property?

Comment: clip is the default value for text-overflow. e.g. text-overflow : clip !important;

Comment: @Billy that did it, thank you! I also had to set white-space:normal  and now it's working perfectly.

Comment: I added the answer to your question for future purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the ellipsis, do the following in your css:

```
.ngHeaderText {
    text-overflow: clip;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

This should fix it!